# How to change click function based on button class in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular I have a button which toggles a class - What I want to do is add events based on the button class. Should this be done via an `If` statement within a function? So far my code is below:

**HTML button**

```
<!-- toggle button --> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-3 btn-button" (click)="status=!status; func()" [ngClass]="{'btn-danger' : status, 'btn-primary' : !status}"  [disabled]="clicked">{{status ? 'Delete' : 'Add'}}</button>
<!-- toggle button -->
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

public btn: any;

func () {
   if (this.btn.hasClass('btn-primary')) {
      alert('Primary clicked');    
   } else if (this.btn.hasClass('btn-danger')) {
     alert('Danger clicked');    
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `status` flag like you already are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdrgde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) may this helps you

You can change class on basics of `action` property;

```
<button (click)="onClick()" [ngClass]="action =='Add' ? 'btn-primary': 'btn-danger'"> {{action}}</button>
```

On button click

```
 onClick() {
    if(this.action == 'Add') {
      this.action = 'Delete';
      alert('Primary Clicked');
    } else {
      this.action = 'Add';
        alert('Danger clicked');    
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the class name, you can check the `status` value.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gwf4i?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
(click)="func()"
```

.ts

```
  func() {
    this.status = !this.status;
    if (this.status) {
      alert("Primary clicked");
    } else if (!this.status) {
      alert("Danger clicked");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but is not explanatory and the else if statement could have been written in a single line (or similar, the else if is totally useless).

Comment: May be check the condition before changing the value of status or it will check for *new* value.

Comment: But that is doing it from a separate click function?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="func()">{{buttontext}}</button>
```

TS

```
buttontext: string = 'ADD';
func () {
    let element = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    element.classList.toggle("btn-danger");
    element.classList.toggle("btn-primary");
    this.buttontext = this.buttontext === 'ADD' ? 'DELETE' : 'ADD';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewchild and ElementRef with a Hostlistener for click event, it would be something like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

@ViewChild('yourButton') deleteAddButton:ElementRef;
func (class) {
   if (deleteAddButton.nativeElement.classList.contains(class)) {
      alert('Primary clicked');    
   } else () {
     alert('Danger clicked');    
   }
 }
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
clickHandler(event) {
  if(deleteAddButton.nativeElement.classList.contains('btn-primary')) {
    this.func('btn-primary');
  }
} 
}
```

In html:

```
<button #deleteAddButton ...</button>
```

Comment: FYI, you can pass the `$event` object into the `(click)` handler: `(click)="muhClickHandler($event")`, you then have all sorts of info on the event in the .ts file of the component.